# Fall down animation on recyclerview horizontal items

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to to apply a fall down animation to recyclerview every time the adapter is updated.

Can you please tell me how I can achieve it?

Here is how my recyclerview looks

[image: Recyclerview with horizontal items]

Comment: What should this "fall down animation" look like? Please post/link an example (image or video) of what your `RecyclerView` should look like afterwards. Are you talking about some type of "drawer fold-out" like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61818692/2016165)?

Comment: This question is already answered. I had everything done which is mentioned in the below answer accept I missed recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation() after data set has changed

Comment: I commented before the answer was posted. ;) A tip for future questions: Describe in detail what you're trying to achieve and post the important bits of your code, so people know what you've already tried. This way it's easier to find problems like the method call you missed. As for xml questions: "before" and "after" images (and if it's just a quick paint drawing) are also good, so people know exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @Neph. Can you have a look at my other question and see if you can find a solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971180/applying-shake-animation-while-retaining-the-scale-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a project: Please call recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation() after the data set changed, if not, the animation would not work.

activity_layout.xml

```
  <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
            android:orientation="vertical">
  </ScrollView>
```

activity_recycler_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".activities.AttendanceActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

item_animation_fall_down.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-20%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="105%"
        android:fromYScale="105%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

</set>
```

layout_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_fall_down"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:delay="15%" />
```

Comment: I have this animation already applied. It works when the recyclerview has items arranged in vertical order. it does not work when the items are arranged horizontally like the picture I have shown

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked after I wrote the code  recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation()

Comment: Can you please have a look at my other question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971180/applying-shake-animation-while-retaining-the-scale-animation